# Is it possible to pass in an existing socket for Twisted to listen on?

Tags: python, twisted, unix-socket, klein-mvc

I'm building some Twisted/Klein services for some command-line tools I am writing and I would like to use systemd's `socket` units. To do that, I would need to accept the socket via a file descriptor when the application starts and pass that socket to Twisted so that it can listen on that socket. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is definitely possible.  In fact, an entire [chapter within the Twisted documentation is dedicated to `systemd`](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/systemd.html); you should read it.

Comment: [This](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/current/core/howto/systemd.html#limitations) section states that twisted cannot accept UNIX domain sockets from systemd... Is that still true, or just outdated documentation?

Comment: It is, sadly, still accurate.  It looks like someone started to contribute the fix, but it was stalled.  Perhaps you could respond to the code review and get it integrated?  https://twistedmatrix.com/trac/ticket/5573